# Copy all tables in database and add new data without affecting the old data SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

Can anyone help me with a stored procedure that would allow all the tables in a database to be copied and the original tables must be truncated at the end, and when the procedure runs everyday all new data must be copied from the original table to the backup tables without affecting the existing data.

This is what I've done

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ZS_Backup
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * INTO
 [dbo].[CS_ArrivalsBackUp], 
 [dbo].[CS_awbBackUp],
 [dbo].[CS_awb_arrivalsBackUp],
 [dbo].[CS_awb_dlvBackUp],
 [dbo].[CS_awb_iataBackUp],
 [dbo].[CS_awb_iata_arrivalsBackUp],
 [dbo].[CS_ConsolidationBackUp],
 [dbo].[CS_part_agents],
 [dbo].[CS_part_consignee],
 [dbo].[Evo_Customers],
 [dbo].[Evo_Products],
 [dbo].[int_log_arrivals],
 [dbo].[int_log_deliveries],
 [dbo].[integration_logs],
 [dbo].[period],
 [dbo].[public_holidays],
 [dbo].[rates],
 [dbo].[temp_Rates]

FROM [dbo].[CS_Arrivals],
       [dbo].[CS_awb],
      [dbo].[CS_awb_arrivals],
      [dbo].[CS_awb_dlv],
      [dbo].[CS_awb_iata],
      [dbo].[CS_awb_iata_arrivals],
      [dbo].[CS_Consolidation],
      [dbo].[CS_part_agents],
      [dbo].[CS_part_consignee],
      [dbo].[Evo_Customers],
      [dbo].[Evo_Products],
      [dbo].[int_log_arrivals],
      [dbo].[int_log_deliveries],
      [dbo].[integration_logs],
      [dbo].[period],
      [dbo].[public_holidays],
      [dbo].[rates],
      [dbo].[temp_Rates]

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[CS_Arrivals],
           [dbo].[CS_awb],
           [dbo].[CS_awb_arrivals],
           [dbo].[CS_awb_dlv],
           [dbo].[CS_awb_iata],
           [dbo].[CS_awb_iata_arrivals],
           [dbo].[CS_Consolidation],
           [dbo].[CS_part_agents],
           [dbo].[CS_part_consignee],
           [dbo].[Evo_Customers],
           [dbo].[Evo_Products],
           [dbo].[int_log_arrivals],
           [dbo].[int_log_deliveries],
           [dbo].[integration_logs],
           [dbo].[period],
           [dbo].[public_holidays],
           [dbo].[rates],
           [dbo].[temp_Rates]

           END
           GO
```

Comment: The answer of your question could be various types. Many architecture and model exist to do this. Question is what are your tryouts or what have you planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

be careful where you run this. For your safety I have commented out the bit that actually does the copy and truncate but instead I have set it so it would show you what would be executed:

```
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR 
FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM sys.tables
WHERE type = 'U'
and name IN ('CS_ArrivalsBackUp', 
'CS_awbBackUp',
'CS_awb_arrivalsBackUp',
'CS_awb_dlvBackUp',
'CS_awb_iataBackUp',
'CS_awb_iata_arrivalsBackUp',
'CS_ConsolidationBackUp',
'CS_part_agents',
'CS_part_consignee',
'Evo_Customers',
'Evo_Products',
'int_log_arrivals',
'int_log_deliveries',
'integration_logs',
'period',
'public_holidays',
'rates',
'temp_Rates')
ORDER BY NAME

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR
INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

PRINT 'SELECT * INTO TMP_' + @table_name + ' FROM ' + @table_name
PRINT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table_name 

--SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO TMP_' + @table_name + ' FROM ' + @table_name
--EXEC (@SQL)

--SET @SQL = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table_name 
--EXEC (@SQL)

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @table_name  

END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
```

Comment: I Keep getting these errors : Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure CopyAndTruncateTables, Line 28
Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * INTO TMP_CS_Arrivals FROM CS_Arrivals'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure CopyAndTruncateTables, Line 31
Could not find stored procedure 'TRUNCATE TABLE CS_Arrivals'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure CopyAndTruncateTables, Line 28
Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * INTO TMP_CS_awb FROM CS_awb'.

Comment: Okay I've updated the code, this is now just a statement and not a stored procedure.  Run it and see what you get back

Comment: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 41
Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * INTO TMP_CS_Arrivals FROM CS_Arrivals'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 44
Could not find stored procedure 'TRUNCATE TABLE CS_Arrivals'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 41

Comment: There is no stored procedure... I have changed the code above, have you copied and pasted the above code in a new window? i.e. code starting with 'DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(1000)' and ending 'DEALLOCATE CUR'

Comment: Hi I've run it and it works 100% Thank you, the only problem is now new data needs to be copied over into these tables daily. Without replacing the existing data.

Comment: Yes the original table but after will the data has been moved. How it works is I have a service running and this stored proc is for the staging area. The data in the staging area gets moved into the back up and the original tables get truncated, than tomorrow the data from the staging area must get added to the backup and the tables truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay only a slight change needed.  Once your temp tables are created (above in the first run); then for future runs you need:

```
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR 
FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM sys.tables
WHERE type = 'U'
and name IN ('CS_ArrivalsBackUp', 
'CS_awbBackUp',
'CS_awb_arrivalsBackUp',
'CS_awb_dlvBackUp',
'CS_awb_iataBackUp',
'CS_awb_iata_arrivalsBackUp',
'CS_ConsolidationBackUp',
'CS_part_agents',
'CS_part_consignee',
'Evo_Customers',
'Evo_Products',
'int_log_arrivals',
'int_log_deliveries',
'integration_logs',
'period',
'public_holidays',
'rates',
'temp_Rates')
ORDER BY NAME

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR
INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

PRINT 'INSERT INTO TMP_' + @table_name + ' SELECT * FROM_' + @table_name
PRINT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table_name 

--SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO TMP_' + @table_name + ' SELECT * FROM_' + @table_name
--EXEC (@SQL)

--SET @SQL = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @table_name 
--EXEC (@SQL)

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @table_name  

END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
```

Comment: Hi sorry what did you change in the second query?

Comment: FROM :SELECT * INTO TMP_ TO: INSERT INTO TMP_

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated